# Debug why IPython is stuck?

Tags: python, ipython, jupyter-notebook

Many times IPython notebook gets stuck showing active cells as `[*]` but not doing anything anymore. This happens on cells which usually only take milliseconds to execute. It may even happen after a fresh startup of IPython. It happens particularly often after `%matplotlib` commands. Occasionally it continues after a very long waiting time.

How can I find out what's going on? Where can I try to find error messages or so?

I've started with the `--debug` option but don't see anything special there. It's certainly possible that the firewall configuration is weird , but how can I configure IPython for that?

Comment: What operation system and backend are you using for matplotlib?

Comment: I have Windows 7. The backend is either qt4 or inline. But this issue is not bound to matplotlib. Sometimes it occurs when I deal with large data which fills most of the memory. Then I try to cancel the command, but nothing happens. Occasionally I see something about KeyboardInterrupt and ZMQ process_event on the console, but apart from "Saving notebook" nothing happens again.

Comment: Interrupting the kernel is a bit tricky on Windows, because there are no signals. In some cases, code can get stuck doing something where it doesn't check for our faked signal.

Comment: So does IPython work better with Linux?